# How can I use a trained GloVe/word2vec model to extract keywords from articles?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have trained a GloVe with ~5M **spanish** articles. I know how to load this GloVe in gensim and use it as if it was a word2vec model.
Now I am facing  the problem of topic modelling and keywords extraction from news articles (also in spanish) so I was wondering how could I use the trained model to do so.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question on how to use a word2vec model is very general so my answer is likewise.

What word2vec allows you to do is to provide a generally "better" representation of words. So perhaps if you are using "bag of words" as a feature in topic modelling you can replace that with a "bag of word vectors" from word2vec which hopefully will give you better semantic similarity. Perhaps better keywords too.

Comment: But how should I represent a text with word2vec? word2vec represent words, not text. Am I right?

Comment: That depends on your problem. Since text is all (or mostly) words you should select some (or all) words in your text to create a word2vec representation. That can be as simple as a sum of the vectors you get from word2vec. You can compare that vector (for instance) with those derived fro your labelled topics using cosine similarity or other metric.

Comment: But if I just sum them, longer texts' vectors will be potentially different from shorter ones even if they use similar words and their meaning is the same. Shouldn't I use another transformation? what about taking the mean from all the words in the text? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely normalize for the length of the text. You may also just want to focus on potentially relevant words - throw out stop words for instance.